# Why isn't my percentage sign being outputted alongside side the integer value?

Tags: javascript, html

The HTML code `<span class="odometer" data-count-to="100"></span>` outputs 100. I want it to count up to and display the percentage sign. For example 100%. How can I do this?

I have tried using using `&#37;` to represent the `%` sign but it doesn't work. `<span class="odometer" data-count-to="100">&#37;</span>`

All that is outputted is 100 with no percentage sign at the end.

```js
  /* Countdown Activation */
        countdownActivation: function () {
            $('.tm-countdown').each(function () {
                var $this = $(this),
                    finalDate = $(this).data('countdown');
                $this.countdown(finalDate, function (event) {
                    $this.html(event.strftime(
                        '<div class="tm-countdown-pack tm-countdown-day"><h2 class="tm-countdown-count">%-D</h2><h5>Days</h5></div><div class="tm-countdown-pack tm-countdown-hour"><h2 class="tm-countdown-count">%-H</h2><h5>Hour</h5></div><div class="tm-countdown-pack tm-countdown-minutes"><h2 class="tm-countdown-count">%M</h2><h5>Min</h5></div><div class="tm-countdown-pack tm-countdown-seconds"><h2 class="tm-countdown-count">%S</h2><h5>Sec</h5></div>'));
                });
            });
        },

        /* CounterUp Activation */
        counterupActivation: function () {
            if ($('.odometer').length) {
                $(window).on('scroll', function () {
                    function winScrollPosition() {
                        var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop(),
                            winHeight = $(window).height();
                        var scrollPosition = Math.round(scrollPos + (winHeight / 1.2));
                        return scrollPosition;
                    }
                    var elemOffset = $('.odometer').offset().top;
                    if (elemOffset < winScrollPosition()) {

                        $('.odometer').each(function () {
                            $(this).html($(this).data('count-to'));
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        },

        /* Wowjs Activation */
        wowJsActive: function () {
            var wow = new WOW({
                boxClass: 'wow',
                animateClass: 'animated',
                offset: 0,
                mobile: true,
                live: true
            });
            wow.init();
        },
```

```html
<span class="odometer" data-count-to="100">&#37;</span>
```

Comment: When I try to run your snippet, I get "SyntaxError: function statement requires a name".

Comment: Sorry I wasn't trying to show my actual code being ran. I just wanted to add a part of my JS incase that was anything to do with it. I'm 100% sure it has something to do with the HTML though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in your `counterupActivation` method, you have this line:

```
$('.odometer').each(function () {
    $(this).html($(this).data('count-to'));
});
```

Notice the line:

```
$(this).html($(this).data('count-to'));
```

What this line do is that it will [replace everything in the HTML with a new value](https://api.jquery.com/html/#html-htmlString). Meaning, your `&#37;` is being overwritten.

What you need to do is to remove `&#37;` from your HTML, and append it in your above line:

```
$('.odometer').each(function () {
    $(this).html($(this).data('count-to') + '&#37;');
});
```